# How to make reference file as numbered instead of author names, in my beamer file?

Tags: latex, beamer, bibliography, biblatex

all I am using the following latex file code in my beamer presentation. My query is how to insert normal numbers in the document as reference, instead of author details.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
    \usepackage[font=tiny,labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    
}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}{m}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, citestyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-ref.bib} %Imports bibliography file
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}


\title[Synopsis Presentation]{\textbf{Sample}} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage 
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents 
    \end{frame}


\begin{frame}
    \section{Introduction}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    This is my first reference \cite{cowie2001emotion}. I want it to be print as [1].
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{References}
    \printbibliography
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{ref.bib}
\end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \centering
        \Huge
        THANK YOU
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This the the bib file :

> @article{cowie2001emotion,
> title={Emotion recognition in human-computer interaction},
> author={Cowie, Roddy and Douglas-Cowie, Ellen and Tsapatsoulis, Nicolas and Votsis, George and Kollias, Stefanos and
> Fellenz, Winfried and Taylor, John G},
> journal={IEEE Signal processing magazine},
> volume={18},
> number={1},
> pages={32--80},
> year={2001},
> publisher={IEEE}
> }

How to do proper referencing here, this bibliography style is also not working.

Comment: You seem to be mixing two different bibliography systems. `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}\bibliography{ref.bib}` is for bibtex, while the rest of your code is for biblatex. If I remove these and compile your file with pdflatex, biber and pdflatex again, I get numeric references https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plz6v.png

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using this?:

```
\usepackage[sortcites,style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

It works for me but tbh I'm not quite sure how or why...